# What's the deal with Roronoa Zoro's eye after the timeskip?

Tags: one-piece

I'm up to date in the *One Piece* anime but not in the manga, is there any information about Zoro's closed eye? Can't he open it because of his scar there, or maybe he is hiding his real power withholding his one eye closed? How did he get his scar? Maybe in a final training fight with Mihawk?

Is there any information about his scar on his eye?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Still, nothing has been revealed if Zoro has some special power in his eye due to which he's keeping it closed. All that's been shown till now is that the scar has greatly injured his eye due to which he cannot open it. [The wiki](https://onepiece.fandom.com/wiki/Roronoa_Zoro#After_the_Timeskip) says the same thing:

> During and after the two-year timeskip, Zoro gains a new scar running down over his left eye, which is now implied to be critically injured as it is always closed.

Yet, Eichiiro sensei hasn't really revealed all of the Strawhat Crew's power, so we can't say anything. So for now, we have only this much information about his eye. Nothing has been shown on how he got it.

Comment: Yeah, wikis aren't always reliable.
But in my opinion the scar does not seem to run as deep to (anime-logically) wound the eye.
So until now we haven't gt the slightest idea what the author is hiding and yes, i also speculate it is a way of limiting his power and skills.

Comment: I assume that the scar was created by a sword. Swordsmen have swords which are just too sharp, so even a minute scratch could damage the eye!

Comment: where was it mentioned that the scar ' has greatly injured his eye due to which he cannot open it.'? as it haven't been mentioned anywhere in manga or anime wiki cannot be relied upon.

Comment: I totally missed that! Do you know which chapter or volume it belongs to?

Comment: The fact that Eiichiro hasnt revealed much it does mean the reason it's somewhat of importance!

Comment: @SK19 if you're referring to the screenshot of the manga panel, [it's fake, a fanmade one](https://www.reddit.com/r/OnePiece/comments/1s21bh/do_they_show_zoro_losing_his_eye_in_the_anime/cdt50hi/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)

Answer (score 0):

Gathering the info I could collect with my observation so far in One Piece anime:

Most of the famous swordsmen  have injuries on their eyes.
Ex: Admiral Ishou, Dark King Silver Rayleigh,

Perhaps It looks like it's considered as an ability of Swordsman to sense the things/people around. Zoro always thrived to learn this technique and succeeded too.

On the otherhand it looks like it's (Kenbunshoku Haki) considered an ultimate ability of swordsman to fight without using Sight sense. So losing sight might be A KEY to AWAKEN ultimate Swordsman powers.
Zoro might have intentionally cut his left eye to awake this ability.
Or he might be still training with his left eye closed. Might open when time comes.

But like other OP fans, I wish to see something special out this.

Comment: Admiral Ishou confirmed that he cut his own eyes, because he didn't want to see all evil out there though. It wasn't related to being a swordsman.

Comment: @PeterRaeves, I remember his statement but that could be one of the reasons for cutting his eyes.

Answer (score -1):

Zoro hasn't shown a MASSIVE change in power after the time skip, at least not as much a Sanji, so he might have something powerful he is gonna use from his eye but it's most likely just a scar from training!